# Memory locations associated with dynamically allocated array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Given the following piece of code:

```
int *myArray = new int[ 1 ];
myArray[0] = 42;

std::cout << "myArray: " << myArray << std::endl;
std::cout << "&myArray: " << &myArray << std::endl;
std::cout << "*myArray: " << *myArray << std::endl;
```

I get the following output:

> myArray: 0x7fca304038c0
>   &myArray: 0x7fff544a9b90
>   *myArray: 42

The result of the dereferencer (e.g., *myArray) makes sense:  it returns the first (and only) element of the array.  But why do myArray and &myArray return different memory locations?

Is myArray the location of the first element of the array in memory?  Indeed, this value is set to 0x0 by setting the array to `NULL`.

Is &myArray is the location of the pointer to myArray in memory -- and thus is not changed by `delete[]` or setting the array to `NULL`?

Comment: It should be `int myArray = {1}` and then it will be an array instead of a pointer, and behave like you seem to be expecting.

Comment: This would certainly be my preference, but I was forced to use a pointer as part of the exercise.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The variable `myArray` is a pointer. The **value** of the pointer is the address returned by your call to `new`

The value of `&myArray` is the **address** in memory of the `myArray` variable. This is different from the address space allocated via `new`

It seems your confusion arises from the distinction between the value of a pointer variable and the address of the pointer variable itself.

Answer (score 3):

The `new` operator allocated space for the array on the heap, which is what you get when you print the *value* of myArray (a pointer to the beginning of the array there). However, the pointer itself is a local variable and resides on the stack, which is what you get when you print the address of myArray (`&myArray`).

`delete[]`-ing this array will invalidate the heap storage you got (so using it afterward, in case you still have that address, will invoke undefined behavior), but will not hurt the pointer itself, just make the value it holds meaningless. You may reuse the same pointer for allocating another array later, for example.

Answer (score 2):

myArray is a pointer to an int, and can also be referenced as an array. So that's why its value is an address.

Meaning:

> Is myArray the location of the first element of the array in memory?
>   Indeed, this value is set to 0x0 upon calling delete[].

Yes

&myArray is the address of this pointer in memory. Pointer to a pointer if you please. So:

> Is &myArray is the location of the pointer to myArray in memory -- and
>   thus is not changed by delete[] or setting the array to NULL?

Also yes.

Unrelated but maybe useful: 
I like this tutorial of pointers. It's clear and has lots of code examples
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/